# How can I save a prerelease PowerShell module to my disk?

Tags: powershell, module

I want to save the newest version of `dbatools` PowerShell module to my disk. I tried:

```
Save-Module -Name dbatools -Path C:\temp
```

But it seems that it only saves the newest stable release, not the newest prerelease. How can I save the newest prerelease?

Answer (score 2):

Note: The following applies analogously to the [`Install-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/PowershellGet/Install-Module) cmdlet.

Use [`Save-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/PowershellGet/Save-Module)'s `-AllowPrerelease` switch to allow downloading pre-release versions.

If you use *only* `-AllowPrerelease`, the *latest* available prerelease version is downloaded:

```bash
# Download and save the latest prerelease version
Save-Module -Name dbatools -Path C:\temp -AllowPrerelease
```

To target a *specific* version, specify it via `-RequiredVersion`

```bash
# Download and save the specified prerelease version,
# such as '2.0.0-preview1' in this example
Save-Module dbatools -Path C:\temp -AllowPrerelease -RequiredVersion 2.0.0-preview1
```

Note:

- The module is downloaded into a subfolder of the target folder specified via `-Path`, named for the module (i.e. `dbatools` in this case).
- Any *dependencies* are downloaded too, using the same save logic, i.e. they are placed in sibling subfolders.

  - Dependencies are those modules listed in the `RequiredModules` entry of the target module's [manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Module_Manifests), which in the case at hand is the `dbatools.library` module.